# Issue trying to create a Ado.Net Entity Model Visual Studio 2013

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 Professional, after install VS I installed MySql for VisualStudio version 1.2.6 that it is the latest release. The problem is when I tried to create a ADO .Net Entity Model I created the connection perfectly fine but when I press Next the window close it self and Visual Studio doesn't create the model.

### Things that I checked:

1. I already have installed in my project the Entity Framework 6, MySQL.Data V6.9.8, MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6 v6.9.8 and MySql.Web v6.9.8.
2. In the Visual Studio Private Libraries there there is the three same libraries with the same version.

I checked other posts here and I really don't find the cause of my problem. I will be very grateful with any help.

### Edit

I attached the process to another instance of Visual Studio and I got this:

```
'devenv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExecutionContextDomain): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'
'devenv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExecutionContextDomain): Unloaded 'C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\3C4YP8TT.W35\4414OC0M.0ZV\4aeb0621\323bbd39_5088d101\SignaSafePro.dll'
'devenv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExecutionContextDomain): Unloaded 'C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\3C4YP8TT.W35\4414OC0M.0ZV\77badc31\29b0d95d_4088d101\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'
'devenv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProjectExecutionContextDomain): Unloaded 'C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\3C4YP8TT.W35\4414OC0M.0ZV\27b7b188\7ad46db4_4f88d101\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.WizardCancelledException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll
The thread 0x908 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

I also uninstall and install all again, the libraries references are exactly the same, because I'm reference the libraries from the PrivateAssemblies folder.

Comment: Add the error message/promp to your post if it does [not] show

Comment: Sorry for the delay but there is no error message, only the dialog close and nothing is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys thank you very much, the problem was my mistake, I thought if I installed just MySQL for Visual Studio was enough but I didn't realized that the MySQL Connector is needed to:
[MySQL Connector/Net Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-install.html)

I hope it serve to guide for anyone other like me.

Comment: Now this will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements**

- Windows OS 7 or later.
- Visual Studio 2010, 2012 or 2013 Professional or higher version.
- Connector/Net 6.8.1 beta or higher version ([MySQL Connector download link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)).

**Additional download links (not required)**

- [MySQL for Visual Studio (latest version)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)